# Using SUBSTR and CHARINDEX into PROC SQL (SAS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas, proc-sql

I have written out a SQL query for Microsoft SQL Server, but now I am trying to convert it into SAS PROC SQL and I am running into issues.

Data:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦════════╗
║   Name   ║ Question ║ Answer ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬════════╣
║ Jane Doe ║ Q1       ║ Q1-Yes ║
║ John Doe ║ Q1       ║ Q1-No  ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

I want to get rid of the "Q1-" in the Answer column and output it as just "Yes" or "No".

In SQL, the code I used is:

```
SUBSTRING (AnswerTXT, CHARINDEX('-', AnswerTXT)+1, LEN (AnswerTXT)) as 'Answer'
```

In SAS,  I figured out I need to change it in PROC SQL. This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(AnswerTXT,
```

I have tried Index and Scan and keep getting this type of error:

```
CLI describe error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]'scan' is not a 
   recognized built-in function name.
```

Thanks!

Comment: will you always have 3 characters you need to strip off, in the `answer` column?

Comment: Why not just use pass-through and write the SQL using native T-SQL?

Comment: @vkp: Sadly no, sometimes it will be more than 3 characters.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I should have mentioned I am a total novice to PROC SQL so I will have to google what that is...

Comment: That error sounds like it *is* a pass through query, @GordonLinoff ... or else this is something else odd.

Comment: @Joe . . . The query has no `scan()` function in it.  Hence, `proc sql` is adding the function, so the query is not being passed through to the database unaltered.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think the question didn't include the correct syntax.

Answer (score 3):

```
SUBSTR(answer, INDEX('-',answer)+1, length(answer))
```

Try this

Comment: The idea is right. But the correct syntax should be: substr(answer, index(answer, '-') + 1); /* tested on data step and proc sql. when the 3rd argument is omitted, the remainder of the string is extracted */